# What is Local space in constraints?

Tags: transforms, constraints

According to Blender's manual:

> Local Space is the parent of the object (or bone) is the frame of
>   reference. Location is relative to the parent object origin. Rotation
>   and Scale are oriented to the parent object axes. Only transformations
>   to the object itself are taken into account. Transformations to the
>   object’s parent are not taken into account.

I do not understand what that all means? What if an object does not have a parent at all? Then what is its local space?

Furthermore, if I use Local space for both the owner and the target of the copy rotation constraint then nothing happens. But if I use the Local spaces for both of them in the copy location constraint then as the target moves along its local axis then the target moves along its own local axis.

Why do we not get the same for the rotation?

Comment: Add an empty make it default cubes parent. Move rotate scale empty anywhere the cube keeps its local transform. The value of location rotation scale of cube in properties is in local space.  If an object does not have a parent can consider it in global space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_coordinates